# NGINX Rewrite Rule without access to the configuration file

Tags: nginx

In apache, the rewrite rule can be written in the configuration file or in .htaccess file. How about in nginx? Can I use url rewriting without access to the configuration file?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. This is one of the reasons shared hostings typically use `apache` or `litespeed`, not `nginx` or `lighttpd`.

A (very ugly) workaround would be to handle all requests with a script which would contain the rewrite rules and would serve the file/script according to the request URI (and which could be modified by a user without having `root` privileges). However you'd have a bad performance serving static files and you'd need to handle all the request headers by this script, which is not very practical.